# Android gridview change background by position

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have Gridview with images. above the image I have text(hello) and I can to show images(without text) to my gridview .now I want if I click gridview's 5th element I want to hide 5th image's text.meybe problem solution is gridview.setOnItemClickListener but I do not know how I can do this
I wrote some code witch can to show toast message by position, but I do not know how I can to hide text by position

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cliked" + position,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `setVisibility` along with an array to sort through the GUI identifiers:

```
    int textId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(position, "id", this.getPackageName());

    TextView picText = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.TextID);
    picText.setVisibility(TextView.INVISIBLE);
```

Or something like that. `INVISIBLE` makes it invisible, but take up the same space - `GONE` will make the space disappear too - so depending on what you want.

That should at least get you in the right direction.

For more: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)

Comment: thanks i know  setVisibility  but i want  to invisible only by position

Comment: Right - findViewById calls an integer value, so you have to use something along the lines of the first line I put to call the correct ID - hence the `getIdentifier(position, "id", this.getPackageName());` line

Answer (score -1):

First Find the `textView` that you want `INVISIBLE`.
Then set it `INVISIBLE`.
By below Code

```
((TextView) v).setVisibility(TextView.INVISIBLE);
```

if above Line dont work use below

```
TextView textview=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.id_of_textview);
textview.setVisibility(TextView.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: Or you could have just +1'ed my comment instead of posting basically the same answer after me.

Comment: you must take view on 'First Find the textView that you want INVISIBLE.'. after my answer you updated your answer.

Comment: another Note: my answer is different to your answer.

Comment: the first post you made was `((TextView) v).setVisibility(TextView.INVISIBLE);`, which a quick search you got from another SO answer... then you got the rest from me ;)